# XML encoding of Attribute in KMIP

Tags: protocols, kmip

I'm analyzing KMIP to implement a prototype in scala. I try so to understand all concepts to implement an architecture for different encoding profiles (bytes, JSON, XML).

In specification section **5.4.1.6 XML Element Encoding**, it stipulates :

> [...] structure values are encoded as nested xml elements, and non-structure
>   values are encoded using the ‘value’ attribute

With this example :

```
<ActivationDate type="DateTime" value="2001-01-01T10:00:00+10:00"/>
```

I don't understand this syntax since *Activation Date* is an attribute. In section **2.1.1 Attribute** an attribute is described with a structure containing *Attribute Name, Attribute Index, Attribute Value*.

The XML representation of an *ActivationDate* or other attributes should be :

```
<Attribute>
    <AttributeName type="TextString" value="Activation Date"/
    <AttributeValue type="DateTime" value="2001-01-01T10:00:00+10:00"/>
</Attribute>
```

Moreover, the [KMIP test case](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/testcases/v1.4/kmip-testcases-v1.4.html) uses this second representation.

If the first representation is shown as an example, it will be used. So in which case ?

Answer (score 1):

The KMIP specification is very vague on this point. BOTH forms of Attribute you described are considered valid KMIP and should be handled.

I strongly recommend the KMIP Additional Message Encodings document when implementing http/json/xml encoding- https://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/kmip-addtl-msg-enc/v1.0/os/kmip-addtl-msg-enc-v1.0-os.html

section 6.1.6 describes yet another format that isn't covered in the main spec: `<TTLV tag="0x420001" name="ActivationDate" type="DateTime" value="2001-01-01T10:00:00+10:00"/>`